# Texture size different in one surface

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm trying to put material on the one surface, but texture size comes out different in certain areas. So the result looks like the material is stretched badly.

I have tried with the check texture to see what's going on and the check texture also stretches some areas.

Is it possible to make all surface to have same size of texture by any chance?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

your model lacks of seams. You can see that even in real life, we have to use mutliple pieces of fabric stiched together in order to make a shoe. The same applies in 3D if you want your uvs to be the less streched possible

[image]

If you don't want your texture to rely on the uv map, you'll have to make procedural textures